# Canvas/Javascript errors in Chrome on specific PC?

Tags: google-chrome, javascript

We have a internal website that we use every day.  Today, I created a new Windows profile on my PC due to some issues I was having.  I later noticed that I was getting javascript errors on the site mentioned above.  I had other users test and they do not get the errors.  I confirmed they are all running the same version of Chrome I am (76.0.3809.100).

After doing some troubleshooting, I have narrowed it down to the following code.

```
canvas.getContext("webgl")
```

On my machine, that returns `null`.  On a working machine, it returns a proper WebGLRenderingContext as expected.

What could possibly be causing this? My first thought was a Chrome extension, but I tested in Incognito mode and got the same result.  I also wondered about a Chrome experimental flag, but again, this is a fresh Windows profile.  It should be all default Chrome settings.

Answer (score 0):

I looked through chrome:flags anyway and saw `Accelerated 2D canvas` was enabled. I disabled it and restarted Chrome and the error no longer occurs.